# Get Firebase event Params for cordova ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I using Ionic 2 to create my app, also I am using the [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase) for analytics.

The plugin works great and I am seeing events in my firebase dashboard.

But I am unable to see the event parameters that I send.

As mentioned in the docs of the plugin I am using the following code to log events and event Params.

```
window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("page_view", {page: "dashboard"});
```

Going through the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events) it is mentioned that Event Params are not shown directly but should appear after setting up "audiences"

> Custom parameters: Custom parameters are not represented directly in your Analytics reports, but they can be used as filters in audience definitions that can be applied to every report. Custom parameters are also included in data exported to BigQuery if your app is linked to a BigQuery project.

I found the way to set up audiences [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317522?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#enable). But am not able to figure our how to set them up.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget, Firebase for Ionic is very young (0.1.17).
I have the same problem than you, maybe the plugin does not send the "value" parameter.

Also the Firebase doc say :

- custom param is include in **BigQuery**.

You can activate it in Analytics > Events.
I have not yet tested this way.

cu

plugin : https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: I am using the same plugin.Took a look at the plugin code for logEvent..Everything looks in order there..As analytics is not populated in realtime it is very frustrating to test. Wish there way an easier way...Do post the solution here when you get to it.